# Entropy variables

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, equilibrium

When we are defining the entropy we have been used two isolated system not a heat bath with a small system, to ensure that entropy is defined as an energy variable dependent. My question why is the entropy defined as (E, V, N) variables not the (T, V, N)?
The same as for Helmholtz free energy is defined as (T, V, N) variables.

Comment: See also [this discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307152/146039) of natural variables and extensivity (switching $U$ and $S$ for relevance to this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question why is the entropy defined as (E, V, N)

In *thermodynamics*, the entropy $S$ is *postulated* to exist, and to obey a maximization principle, **and** to be a function of the macroscopic state, which is determined by the triple: $E$, $V$, and $N$. This is *by definition*.

In other words, we choose to use the symbol $S$ and the name "entropy" for *the* thermodynamic potential that is *maximized* as a function of $E$, $V$, and $N$. That's it!

If we do not want to consider the macrostate in terms of $E$, $V$, and $N$, we can Legendre Transform and consider different thermodynamic potentials, such as the Helmholtz Free Energy.

By convention (or by definition, if you prefer) we agree to use the symbol $F$ and the name "Helmholtz Free Energy" for the Legendre Transformation of the entropy $S$ with respect to $E$:
$$
F(T,V,N) \equiv \inf_{E}\left(\frac{1}{T} E - S(E,V,N)\right)\;.
$$

Please see Chapter 1 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html) for more details. (N.b., I did not write this book and I am not affiliated with this book. I just like it.)

Comment: thank you for all of the information now the problem is solved for me, and for the book that you recommended, I was looking for something similar so i'm grateful to you

Comment: @Fadi You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the second law of thermodynamics in differential form $ TdS(E, V, N) = dE + pdV - \mu dN$, which tells us what differentials of what variable change the differential of the thermodynamic potential under study.

So to understand what natural units a thermodynamic potential has it is necessary to calculate its differential using its formula. For instance

$dF = dE - d(TS) = TdS - pdV + \mu dN - TdS - SdT = -SdT - pdV + \mu dN; \ F=F(T, V, N)$

Comment: well i think it's a good way to think about it , but i was asking about the definition of the entropy and the helmholtz free energy and the postulates that have been used .